# Is there a way for an object to reference itself inside its constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor

The explanation is simpler with a code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        A newObjectA = new A(new B(newObjectA));
    }
    class A{
        A(B b){
            //constructor code...
        }
    }
    class B{
        A refernceToA;
        B(A a){
            this.refernceToA = a;
            //constructor code...
        }
    }
}
```

For this I got the following error:

`The local variable newObjectA may not have been initialized`

My solution right now is to simply make 1 more method besides the constructor, e.g. setB(), but I would like to now if the is a way to overcome this.

Comment: No, this wont be possible without a setter. You have a circular dependency here. Java is actually protecting you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to call it before it gets declared, however like you said you could:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    B newObjectB = new B();
    A newObjectA = new A(newObjectB);
    newObjectB.setA(newObjectA);
}

class A{
    A(B b){
        //constructor code...
    }
}

class B{
    A refernceToA;

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.refernceToA = a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple way to do it, because A hasn't been instantiated when the nested B is being instantiated.

```java
A newObjectA = new A(new B());
```

can also be written as

```java
B newObjectB = new B();
A newObjectA = new A(newObjectB);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to eliminate this circular class dependency might be by creating another class which depends on both A and B;

From this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

    class A {
        B b;

        A(B b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        void methodUsingBInstance() {
            // ...
        }

        void someOtherMethod() {
            // ...
        }
    }

    class B {
        A a;

        B(A a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        void methodUsingAInstance() {
            // ...
        }

        void someOtherMethod() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

    class A {
        void someOtherMethod() {
            // ...
        }
    }

    class B {
        void someOtherMethod() {
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    class C {
        A a;
        B b;
        
        C(A a, B b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        void methodUsingBInstance() {
            // ...
        }

        void methodUsingAInstance() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```